# Class 'ZendPdf\PdfDocument' not found

Tags: php

Class 'ZendPdf\PdfDocument' not found
In my controller:
use `ZendPdf\PdfDocument`;

```
public function pdfAction(){ $pdf = new PdfDocument(); 
$pdf->pages[0] = new Page(     Page::SIZE_A4 ); 
$pdf->pages[0]->setFont(Font::fontWithName( Font::FONT_HELVETICA ), 24 );
$pdf->pages[0]->drawText( 'Hello world!', 240, 400 );$pdf->save( 'example.pdf' );
```

}

Comment: are u using `auto-loading ?`

Comment: Then you need to include that class manually.

Comment: when I include my class name manually??? pdfdocument1 also I m getting error,,class not found

Answer (score 0):

Upload composer properly and put this code in controller

```
public function pdfAction()
{ 
$pdf = new PdfDocument(); 
$pdf->pages[0] = new Page(Page::SIZE_A4 ); 
$pdf->pages[0]->setFont(Font::fontWithName( Font::FONT_HELVETICA ), 24 );
$pdf->pages[0]->drawText( 'Hello world!', 240, 400 );
$pdf->save( 'example.pdf' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

install composer and run this code into your command prompt

```
Composer require "ZendFramework/ZendPdf":"2.0.2"
```